# How to create xib for static cell and display in table view in interface builder?

Tags: swift3, swift2, interface-builder, xib, uitableview

In Xcode 8.x I have a cell layout that I've created in IB that has it's own xib. I'd like to use the cell xib I've created in several difference scenes, the xib would be displayed in static cells in a UITableViewController.  Is this doable or do I have to re-create the static cells in every scene that I want a cell like this?  There must be a way to do this, right?

An example of my xib (which has the accompanying .swift file):
[image]

How can I cause the xib to display within the table view in IB?  I've been able to create the cells programmatically and get them to display at run-time in the table view, but it would REALLY nice if I could select a cell in the tableview, then set the custom class (or whatever needs to be done) so that IB would display the xib in-place in the static cell.

For example, set the custom class here:
[image]

And have the storyboard display like this:
[image]

Comment: I would like to know an answer to this question too!